# No such file or directory : app.ap_

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

When i try to run my application it gives me this error.. But why ?

```
[ERROR] Exception occurred while building Android project:
[ERROR] Traceback (most recent call last):
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\ThomasBolander\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\2.1.2.GA\android\builder.py", line 2243, in <module>
[ERROR]     s.build_and_run(True, avd_id, device_args=device_args)
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\ThomasBolander\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\2.1.2.GA\android\builder.py", line 2068, in build_and_run
[ERROR]     launched, launch_failed = self.package_and_deploy()
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\ThomasBolander\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\2.1.2.GA\android\builder.py", line 1585, in package_and_deploy
[ERROR]     unsigned_apk = self.create_unsigned_apk(ap_)
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\ThomasBolander\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\2.1.2.GA\android\builder.py", line 1447, in create_unsigned_apk
[ERROR]     resources_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(resources_zip_file)
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\ThomasBolander\AppData\Local\Titanium Studio\plugins\com.appcelerator.titanium.python.win32_1.0.0.1338515509\python\lib\zipfile.py", line 671, in __init__
[ERROR]     self.fp = open(file, modeDict[mode])
[ERROR] IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\ThomasBolander\\Dropbox\\Praktikanten\\Apps\\Fritidsjob.dk Android Standard\\build\\android\\bin\\app.ap_'
```

Comment: If that is a Dropbox(.com) synced folder: try compiling that project outside of it, dropbox is maybe trying to sync files in a way that interferes with the build process. Cleaning the project is also helping a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Make sure that if you are using localization files, there are no errors in those.
2. If you are using any kind of module, make sure that module is compatible with your SDK.
3. Clean your solution and then run the project again.

Comment: Revieweing your first answer here: can you please avoid abbreviations like "u r"? Just a comment!