# Error building project : Titanium mobile

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I have an app written using Titanium Mobile platform, and it works great on the simulator, but when I try to build for my device, it gives this error.

```
[INFO] Performing clean build
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.1/iphone/builder.py", line 1296, in main
    execute_xcode("iphoneos%s" % iphone_version,args,False)
  File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.1/iphone/builder.py", line 1057, in execute_xcode
    output = run.run(args,False,False,o)
  File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.1/iphone/run.py", line 39, in run
    sys.exit(rc)
SystemExit: 1
```

Anyone got any idea what this error is about?

Comment: That's not a very descriptive error, unfortunately. To get more information on what's going wrong, can you open the Xcode project in build/iphone, and try deploying to device from there?

Comment: I did that - and found out the issue that way. I also found a log file: `build/iphone/build/build.log` which probably would be more revealing. Very bad error reporting from titanium, which really feels like it is cobbled together with pritt stick and thumb tacks sometimes. Turns out my error was with an expired key during the codesign process - by the solution is to hunt down the meaningful error message - whatever it may be. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments...

> That's not a very descriptive error, unfortunately. To get more
>   information on what's going wrong, can you open the Xcode project in
>   build/iphone, and try deploying to device from there? – Dawson Toth 23
>   hours ago
>
> I did that - and found out the issue that way. I also found a log
>   file: build/iphone/build/build.log which probably would be more
>   revealing. Very bad error reporting from titanium, which really feels
>   like it is cobbled together with pritt stick and thumb tacks
>   sometimes. Turns out my error was with an expired key during the
>   codesign process - by the solution is to hunt down the meaningful
>   error message - whatever it may be. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when i tried to install my project to my device. I had used the following steps

- Clean your project (Project -> Clean)
- Close your Simulator
- Restart your Titanium studio
- Then Install the project to your device

Hope this helped you!!

Comment: I read that has helped other people on the forums, but in my case it did not. The real problem is the very generic error reporting from Titanium, so you end up stabbing wildly in the dark to solve any issue. Thanks for the suggestion - maybe it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Make sure that if you are using localization files, there are no errors in those.
If you are using any kind of module, make sure that module is compatible with your SDK.
Clean your solution and then run the project again.
rest your Simulator

same question is asked here

[No such file or directory : app.ap_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482380/no-such-file-or-directory-app-ap)